# Calculation of R^2 value for a non-linear regression

Tags: r, statistics, regression, non-linear-regression

I would first like to say, that I understand that calculating an R^2 value for a non-linear regression isn't exactly correct or a valid thing to do.

However, I'm in a transition period of performing most of our work in SigmaPlot over to R and for our non-linear (concentration-response) models, colleagues are used to seeing an R^2 value associated with the model to estimate goodness-of-fit.

SigmaPlot calculates the R^2 using 1-(residual SS/total SS), but in R I can't seem to extract the total SS (residual SS are reported in summary).

Any help in getting this to work would be greatly appreciated as I try and move us into using a better estimator of goodness-of-fit.

Cheers.

Comment: Perhaps math.stackexchange.com might be able to offer more assistance?

Comment: Are you using `fit <- nls(y ~x); summary(fit)`?

Comment: @DiggyF -- yes, exactly that.

Comment: I just figured it out... sometimes asking a question, crystallizes things for you.

`test.mdl<-nls(ctrl.adj~a/(1((conc.calc/x0)^b)),
data=dataSet,
start=list(a=100,b=10,x0=40),
trace=T);
# R^2 can then be calculated by:
1-(deviance(test.mdl)/sum((ctrl.adj-mean(ctrl.adj))^2))`

I get the same r^2 as when using SigmaPlot, so all should be good.

Comment: There's an old discussion on it here: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2002-July/023461.html

Comment: @aule You should post your answer in the Answer box.  Give yourself a little checkmark :)

Comment: @mcpeterson I will post the solution, but I'm new here and have to wait 24 hrs...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of extracting the total SS, I've just calculated them:

```
test.mdl <- nls(ctrl.adj~a/(1((conc.calc/x0)^b)),
                data=dataSet,
                start=list(a=100,b=10,x0=40), trace=T);

1 - (deviance(test.mdl)/sum((ctrl.adj-mean(ctrl.adj))^2))
```

I get the same R^2 as when using SigmaPlot, so all should be good.

Answer (score 5):

So the total variation in y is like (n-1)*var(y) and the proportion not explained my your model is `sum(residuals(fit)^2)` so do something like `1-(sum(residuals(fit)^2)/((n-1)*var(y))  )`